# Flatlist item redirects to details page

Tags: react-native

I am new at react native and I am trying to make a detail page for my crypto price API.
What I need to do is when the user press on crypto he is redirected to a detail screen page where he can see charts, price etc. I have no idea what I should do next, I tried onpress() but it did not work. How can I make those flatList elements that are displayed using `CryptoList` when clicking on them shows detail page?

App.js

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCoinData, setSelectedCoinData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMarketData = async () => {
      const marketData = await getMarketData();
      setData(marketData);
    }
    fetchMarketData();
  }, [])
  

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.titleWrap}>
        <Text style={styles.largeTitle}>
           Crypto
        </Text>
      <Divider width={1} style={styles.divider} />
      </View>
   <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <CryptoList
            name={item.name}
            symbol={item.symbol}
            currentPrice={item.current_price}
            priceChangePercentage={item.price_change_percentage_24h}
            logoUrl={item.image}
          />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

cryptoList.js

```
const CryptoList = ({ name, symbol, currentPrice, priceChangePercentage, logoUrl}) => {
  const priceChangeColor = priceChangePercentage > 0 ? 'green'  : 'red';
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity>
    <View style={styles.itemWrapper}>

      {/*Left side view*/}
      <View style={styles.leftWrap}>
      <Image source={{uri: logoUrl}} style={styles.image}/>
      <View style={styles.titleWrapper}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>{ name }</Text>
        <Text style={styles.subtitle}>{ symbol.toUpperCase() }</Text>
      </View>
      </View>
       {/*Right side view*/}
      <View style={styles.rightWrap}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>€{currentPrice.toLocaleString('de-DE', {currency: 'Eur'})}</Text>
        <Text style={[styles.subtitle,{color: priceChangeColor} ]}>{priceChangePercentage.toFixed(2)}%</Text>
      </View>

    </View>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import { Divider, useTheme } from 'react-native-elements';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { HomeScreen } from './pages/homeScreen';
// You can import from local files
import CryptoList from './components/cyproList';
// or any pure javascript modules available in npm
import { Card } from 'react-native-paper';
import { getMarketData } from './components/cryptoApi';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [selectedCoinData, setSelectedCoinData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMarketData = async () => {
      const marketData = await getMarketData();
      setData(marketData);
    }
    fetchMarketData();
  }, [])
  

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.titleWrap}>
        <Text style={styles.largeTitle}>
           Kriptovalūtu cenas
        </Text>
      <Divider width={1} style={styles.divider} />
      </View>
   <FlatList
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <CryptoList
            name={item.name}
            symbol={item.symbol}
            currentPrice={item.current_price}
            priceChangePercentage={item.price_change_percentage_24h}
            logoUrl={item.image}
          />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  titleWrap:{
    marginTop:50,
    paddingHorizontal: 15,
  },
  largeTitle:{
    fontSize: 22,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  divider: {
    marginTop: 10,
  }
});

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<div data-snack-id="2OtINTPVy" data-snack-platform="android" data-snack-preview="true" data-snack-theme="light" style="overflow:hidden;background:#F9F9F9;border:1px solid var(--color-border);border-radius:4px;height:505px;width:100%"></div>
<script async src="https://snack.expo.dev/embed.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

your code seems incomplete. Have you tried  w`onPress={() => navigate(DetailsPage, {selectedCoinData})}` where selectedCoinData is the details of your coin, then on details page you can retrieve the info with the params of react navigation with `const route = useRoute()` and use `route.params.selectedCoinData`

```
   <FlatList
    keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
    data={data}
    renderItem={({ item }) => (
      <CryptoList
        name={item.name}
        symbol={item.symbol}
        currentPrice={item.current_price}
        onPress={() => navigate(DetailsPage, {selectedCoinData})}
        priceChangePercentage={item.price_change_percentage_24h}
        logoUrl={item.image}
      />
    )}
  />
```

and then in your component

```
    const CryptoList = ({ name, symbol, currentPrice, priceChangePercentage, logoUrl, onPress}) => { return (
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I tried some onPress methods but it did nto work. Can you please show us in withch place I should put `onPress={() => navigate(DetailsPage, {selectedCoinData})}`

Comment: I edited the answer to show, no problem, let me know if you need more info

Comment: I couldn't get this to work.  Why should I add onPress on `const CryptoList` , I need it to show the list. Sorry, I am confused, I think this is not so hard to fix, but I just do not understand how all this react native staff works together.

Comment: You are passing the onPress function you declare in App.js to your CryptoList component

Comment: can you send the error you get?

Comment: Also can you share your details page?

Comment: Ok I think I understand your problem, you haven't created your navigation stack, have a look at react-navigation documentation to see how to create a navigation stack

Comment: Yes correct I have not created a navigation stack. 
You can see the full code here - https://snack.expo.dev/F0rO3KVma

Comment: unfortunately I will not write your code for you, but everything I told you is correct check the react-navigation write a stack and add my snippet and your code will work. If you could validate the answer will be very appreciated, good luck